# Cómo dar un nuevo lugar a un botón cuando la página es responsiva?

Tags: html, css

En mi página tengo un carousel y dentro de ella tengo un botón el cual quiero que al momento de que lo visualice desde un dispositivo móvil aparezca fuera del carousel. Por el momento ya tengo las propiedades de mi botón cuando sea responsivo pero lo que no se es como podría ponerlo en otro lado de la página.
Si alguien me pudiera orientar se lo agradecería mucho.

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                @{var count = -1;
                foreach (var Dashboardsl in ViewBag.aprobadas)
                {
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@(++count)" class="@(count==0? "active":"")"></li> 
                    </ol>
                }}
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    @{var countb = -1;
                    foreach (var Dashboard in ViewBag.aprobadas)
                    {
                    <div class="item @((countb++)==0? "active": "")">
                        <a href="@Dashboard.URL_PDF">
                            <img src="@Dashboard.URL_IMG" style="width:auto; height:auto;">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                        <!-------- ESTE ES MI BOTON -------->
                        <a href="#" id="scroll-down" class="text-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"></a>
                    } }
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi hoja de estilo en la parte para el dispositivo móvil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres poner el botón debajo del carousel y centrado horizontalmente?

Comment: Exactamente así @GustavoGarcía

Answer (score 1):

Aplica `position: relative` a `#myCarousel` y al botón un `position: absolute` cuando la resolución sea la deseada.

**Ejemplo**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
  #scroll-down { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 115%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

Esto hará que, cuando el ancho máximo de la pantalla sea 320 pixeles, el botón tenga un posicionamiento absoluto y tome como referencia al carousel para que se ponga debajo del este y se centre horizontalmente en la pantalla.

Comment: Use tú ejemplo pero al correr la página el botón no me sale, se debe a las propiedades que se han puesto? He tratado de usar `z-index:1` pero no funciona. sabes a que se debe?

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda Si el resto de elementos (debajo del carousel) tiene un `z-index` fijo entonces el botón debe tener un valor superior. Así mismo, no olvides hacer al carousel `relative`, de lo contrario, el botón tomará como referencia al body y al tener `top: 115%` se saldría de cuadro.

Comment: De echo así lo tengo como me dices pero de igual forma no puedo visualizar mi botón

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda inspecciona el documento y fíjate si el botón está oculto por otro elemento.

Comment: Me sale debajo del carousel, y se supone que no esta oculto por otro elemento pero es raro porque no logro hacer que se muestre.

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda dale un `z-index` muy alto y prueba. También revisa si no hay ningún `opacity` o `visibility` que afecte.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61695/discussion-between-amairani-fernanda-and-gustavo-garcia).